# WARNING: JAXP feature XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING on Jersey2.x Client

Tags: jersey-client, jersey-2.0

Sep 22, 2013 5:15:00 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SecureSaxParserFactory

```
WARNING: JAXP feature XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING cannot be set on a SAXParserFactory. External general entity processing is disabled but other potential security related features will not be enabled.
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SecureSaxParserFactory.<init>(SecureSaxParserFactory.java:107)...
```

I can use 
`config.getFeatures().put(FeaturesAndProperties.FEATURE_DISABLE_XML_SECURITY, true);`

to avoid this warning message on **Jersey1.x**, but when I migrated to **Jersey2.x**, there's no this feature setting.
How could I do to avoid it again on Jersey2.x?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In JAXP 1.3, which is bundled with Java 1.5 and available as an option
>   in earlier versions, you can limit all of these potential overflows by
>   setting the SAX feature
>   http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
>   (XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING). Once you've set that
>   feature, any excessively long constructs -- whether too many
>   attributes in an element or too many characters in an element name --
>   will be treated as well-formedness errors. This means you may end up
>   rejecting some genuinely well-formed documents; however, the default
>   values are quite large and can handle most realistic documents.

In Jersey2.x, to check if disable this feature is here:
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractXmlFactory
boolean isXmlSecurityDisabled() {
    return PropertiesHelper.isProperty(config.getProperty(MessageProperties.XML_SECURITY_DISABLE));
}
We can find that Jersey uses MessageProperties.XML_SECURITY_DISABLE parameter to check this setting.

So, we can set it separately:
Server:

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class XXXResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public XXXResourceConfig() {
        packages("xxx.yyy.zzz");
        property(MessageProperties.XML_SECURITY_DISABLE, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
...
config.property(MessageProperties.XML_SECURITY_DISABLE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

feuyeux's code is working fine. Thanks.

JAX-RS client code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.property(MessageProperties.XML_SECURITY_DISABLE, Boolean.TRUE);
client.target("http://localhost:7101/helloword/rest").path("dummy").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the above answer is really good in this case. But for completeness I add what I found out when investigating this. According to [this post](http://gangmax.me/blog/2014/01/24/resolve-the-warning-jaxp-feature-xmlconstants-dot-feature-secure-processing-cannot-be-set-on-a-saxparserfactory-problem/) an old version of `xerces` may cause the problem. It can be implicitly added by other dependencies and needs to be excluded in those cases.